# Why doesn't Haskell's Prelude.read return a Maybe?

Tags: parsing, haskell, types

Is there a good reason why the type of Prelude.read is

```
read :: Read a => String -> a
```

rather than returning a `Maybe` value?

```
read :: Read a => String -> Maybe a
```

Since the string might fail to be parseable Haskell, wouldn't the latter be be more natural?

Or even an `Either String a`, where `Left` would contain the original string if it didn't parse, and `Right` the result if it did?

**Edit:**

I'm not trying to get others to write a corresponding wrapper for me. Just seeking reassurance that it's safe to do so.

Comment: Why doesn't `take` accept any `Num a => a`? Why is there a special case of `fmap` for lists? Why is `Functor` not required for `Monad` instances? I expect the answer to be similar to the answers to these and related questions.

Comment: Well, that's why I phrased it the way I did, leaving the option open that there is no good reason. While I also suspect there might not be, like for the well-known examples you give, it's worth asking to make sure that writing my own wrapper won't create unforeseen problems downstream.

Comment: I hope a `readMaybe` function will be added soon.

Comment: Good points @delnan, but shouldn't `take` be `Integral n => n -> [a] -> [a]`?

Comment: @DougMcClean: Yes, it should actually be `Integral`, not `Num` - brain fart.

Comment: Another cool version of `maybeRead` [here](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/cgi/latest/doc/html/src/Network-CGI-Protocol.html#maybeRead).

Comment: @delnan There's a reason for there being a special version of `fmap` for lists; they decided beginners were too easily confused by the generality, so called the generalised Functor version `fmap` instead of `map` to give more helpful error messages. Similarly they decided to use `do` notation instead of Monad comprehension (as originally envisaged by Wadler), so that comprehension notation was specific to lists. (It also allows you to finish with something other than `return x`.)

Comment: @AndrewC and in the same vein, a `read` that throws an exception is easier for beginners than involving `Maybe a` right off the bat, I assume.

Comment: @user395760 Functor *is* required for Monad these days: Functor is a superclass of Applicative, which is a superclass of Monad. I think this changed a couple years ago.

Answer (score 115, accepted):

**Edit**: As of GHC 7.6, `readMaybe` is available in the `Text.Read` module in the base package, along with `readEither`: http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Text-Read.html#v:readMaybe

---

Great question! The type of read itself isn't changing anytime soon because that would break lots of things. However, there *should* be a `maybeRead` function.

Why isn't there? The answer is "inertia". There was a [discussion in '08](http://haskell.1045720.n5.nabble.com/Proposal-Add-Text-Read-maybeRead-Read-a-gt-String-gt-Maybe-a-td3174167.html) which got derailed by a discussion over "fail."

The good  news is that folks were sufficiently convinced to start moving away from fail in the libraries. The bad news is that the proposal got lost in the shuffle. There *should* be such a function, although one is easy to write (and there are zillions of very similar versions floating around many codebases).

See also [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2931557/haskell-check-for-user-input-errors).

Personally, I use the version from the [safe package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/safe).

Answer (score 32):

Yeah, it would be handy with a read function that returns Maybe.  You can make one yourself:

```
readMaybe :: (Read a) => String -> Maybe a
readMaybe s = case reads s of
              [(x, "")] -> Just x
              _ -> Nothing
```

Comment: Thank you! I hope the edit doesn't sound ungrateful! :) Just want to make it clear I'm not asking out of laziness...

Comment: If @augustss can't provide it, a better answer may not exist.

Comment: I don't think a maybe version was ever discussed in the original design.  Many of these things become obvious with experience, but can be hard to predict.

Comment: The _reason_ that reads returns a list is for the case where there are  multiple valid parses.  The Maybe case is intermediate between reads and read.

Comment: I think this requires `Read a` typeclass: `readMaybe :: Read a => String -> Maybe a`

Comment: Where is `x` defined?

Comment: @nyuszika7h It's bound in the pattern in the case.

Comment: When does `reads` return a list containing more than one result? That is, give an example for an expression that has multiple valid parses.

Comment: FYI to readers post GHC 7.6, there is now a `readMaybe` function that can be imported from the `Text.Read` library.

Answer (score 15):

Apart from inertia and/or changing insights, another reason might be that it's aesthetically pleasing to have a function that can act as a kind of inverse of `show`. That is, you want that `read . show` is the identity (for types which are an instance of `Show` and `Read`) and that `show . read` is the identity on the range of `show` (i.e. `show . read . show == show`)

Having a `Maybe` in the type of `read` breaks the symmetry with `show :: a -> String`.

Comment: Thanks for adding a new angle! That makes sense. But to achieve that cleanly, wouldn't it make sense to have both show and read produce a distinct type, say "ParseableString"?

Comment: @BilalBarakat: The distinct type could be `newtype ValidShow a = ValidShow String`. The phantom type makes it more type-safe.

Comment: It's an interesting point, but ultimately, a false symmetry.  Programmers should value correctness over aesthetics.

Comment: @yairchu It wasn't immediately obvious to me what you meant about the phantom type, so I'll clarify in case anyone else is confused like I was. You intend something like `showThing :: Show a => a -> ValidShow a` and `readThing :: Read a => ValidShow a -> a`, so that the type of the thing that was shown is remembered in the ValidShow object. This way you can't write `readThing (showThing True) :: String`.

Answer (score 12):

As @augustss pointed out,  you can make your own safe read function.   However, his `readMaybe` isn't completely consistent with read,  as it doesn't ignore whitespace at the end of a string.  (I made this mistake once,  I don't quite remember the context)

Looking at the [definition of read in the Haskell 98 report](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/standard-prelude.html#%24vread),  we can modify it to implement a `readMaybe` that is perfectly consistent with `read`,  and this is not too inconvenient because all the functions it depends on are defined in the Prelude:

```
readMaybe        :: (Read a) => String -> Maybe a
readMaybe s      =  case [x | (x,t) <- reads s, ("","") <- lex t] of
                         [x] -> Just x
                         _   -> Nothing
```

Comment: Thanks! +1 for alerting me to the whitespace issue, which hadn't been made explicit before.

Comment: Note that if you just use the `safe` package, you get a correct version of `readMaybe` available (it's called `readMay` and it's identical to this version.

Answer (score 8):

This function (called [`readMaybe`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Text-Read.html#v%3areadMaybe)) is now in the Haskell prelude! (As of the current base -- 4.6)

Comment: Well, the linked text says it's in Text.Read and not in Prelude (May have changed), however, it still helped me!